# Statistical model Regression

Tags: regression, model

A statistical model is often defined as a set of probability distributions on a random variable of interest, indexed by a parameter $\theta$; hence, for continuous random variables  equivalently as a set of probability density functions $\{p(y;\theta) : \theta \in \Theta\}$.

Let $y$ be sample and $x$ a fixed value accompanying to the sample. I would than argue that using the above definition of statistical model

$\{\mathcal{N(y;1,\theta)}:\theta \in \mathbb{R_0^+}\}$ is a statistical model. It is as set of distributions indexed by $\theta$.

$\{\mathcal{N(y;x,\theta)}:\theta \in \mathbb{R_0^+}\}$ is not a statistical model as it is not set of distributions indexed by $\theta$. It rather is a set distributions indexed by $(x,\theta)$. However, $x$ can clearly not be treated as a parameter of the model. 
Alternatively, is a set of families of distributions index by $\theta$, which are themselves indexed by x.

Yet, I think we would all say that $p(y)=\mathcal{N(y;x,\theta)}$ *is* a statistical
 model.

Is this

1. impreciseness?
2. fine as my argument that $\{\mathcal{N(y;x,\theta)}:\theta \in \mathbb{R_0^+}\}$ is not a statistical model is flawed? If so how would you argue that $\{\mathcal{N(y;x,\theta)}:\theta \in \mathbb{R_0^+}\}$ is a statistical model?
3. fine as my definition of statistical model is not the standard one? If so what is the standard definition of a statistical model?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking: whether "$x$" is present or not in the formulas, both models manifestly accord with both definitions.  In both cases the model is a set of probability distributions indexed by the parameter $\theta$.

Comment: You might be right. For me the pure statistical model definition does not fit with the statistical model for regression as the probability density of y is not completely determined by knowing $\theta$, one also has to know $x$.

Comment: I modified the question to clarify my thoughts.

Comment: Thank you.  I am missing the thought, otherwise not explicitly expressed, that connects "...also needs to know $x$" and "... since $x$ is fixed ... ."  Within that gap, you appear to acknowledge that you *do* know $x$--so what's the problem? Consider an extreme case of this model, that $(y_i)$ are a sample from a Normal$(x,\sigma^2)$ distribution and you know $x=1$. Doesn't that obviously define a family of distributions (parameterized by $\sigma$ alone)?

Comment: Thanks for sticking around. I think your example is very well suited for further discussion. I agree for a fixed $x$ value this would obviously be a statistical model. However, every sample $y_i$ has its own statistical model: $N(x_i,\sigma^2)$. I don't see how the classical definitions of statistical models allows the set of distributions to be different for every sample. It only allows one set of probability distributions for the random vector $Y$ of which the sample is a realization.

Comment: I have read this over three times since your edit and still cannot find any question in the post.  What are you trying to ask?

Comment: I have modified my original question again. I have also added a question.